# Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList in android studio

Tags: java, android

I am trying to permanently save some of the visited places by the user. So, when ever i run my project in android studio i get the error 
"Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList"

Here is my code:

```html
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static ArrayList<String> places= new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<LatLng> locations = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.lucifer.memorableplaces", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        ArrayList<String> latitudes = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> longitudes = new ArrayList<>();

        places.clear();
        latitudes.clear();
        longitudes.clear();
        locations.clear();

        try {

            places =  (ArrayList<String>)ObjectSerializer.deserialize(sharedPreferences.getString("places", ObjectSerializer.serialize(new ArrayList<String>())));

            latitudes = (ArrayList<String>) ObjectSerializer.deserialize(sharedPreferences.getString("latitudes", ObjectSerializer.serialize(new ArrayList<String>())));

            longitudes = (ArrayList<String>) ObjectSerializer.deserialize(sharedPreferences.getString("longitudes", ObjectSerializer.serialize(new ArrayList<String>())));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (places.size() > 0 && latitudes.size() > 0 && longitudes.size() > 0) {

            if (places.size() == latitudes.size() && latitudes.size() == longitudes.size()) {

                for (int i = 0; i < latitudes.size(); i++) {

                    locations.add(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latitudes.get(i)), Double.parseDouble(longitudes.get(i))));

                }


            }


        } else {

            places.add("Add a new place...");
            locations.add(new LatLng(0, 0));

        }

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, places);

        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("placeNumber", i);

                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });


    }
}
```

and i get the following error:

```html
 Process: com.example.lucifer.memorableplaces, PID: 15910
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lucifer.memorableplaces/com.example.lucifer.memorableplaces.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2378)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5433)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
                      at com.example.lucifer.memorableplaces.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5301)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2291)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2378) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5433) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The error is at 
   places =  (ArrayList)ObjectSerializer.deserialize(sharedPreferences.getString("places", ObjectSerializer.serialize(new ArrayList())));

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the answer, the error was caused because i was casting a class to arrayList. so i just changed my class to arrayList first then i casted it back to arrayList which solved my problem.

This way. Here i coded MainActivity.class

```html
 sharedPreferences.edit().putString("places",ObjectSerializer.serialize(MainActivity.class)).apply();
```

Whereas it has to be MainActivity.places in following Way

```html
 sharedPreferences.edit().putString("places",ObjectSerializer.serialize(MainActivity.places)).apply();
```

So, here i was actually casting a class to arrayList which gave me this error. Hope any beginner will prevent this mistake from this Question.

Thanks You All...